# Using Testflight to test iOS 11 beta apps?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I can't upload apps from Xcode 9 and iOS 11 to AppStore even for beta testing. Is this supposed to work? If not, what is the best way to let other users beta test iOS 11 stuff?

Comment: I would recommend to use third-party distribution systems like Fabric.

Comment: iOS 11 beta questions are better suited for Apple's developer forums. https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/beta/ios-11-beta. Here is a possible solution for your issue from their forums. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/236623#236623